# Why does my rewrite rule only work on specific word?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need a rewrite rule, which rewrites every request to `index.php`, except when the word `web` is in the url. So, every image, JS, CSS file is located under the web folder. Here are my `.htaccess` file which currently does the trick:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # Folders / files to exclude from rewrite divided by Pipe goes here:
    RewriteRule (^|/)web(/|$) - [L,NC]

    # turn empty requests into requests for "index.php",
    # keeping the query string intact
    RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !favicon.ico$
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]

    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

This works for:

```
http://localhost/~alpham8/application/index/index/
http://localhost/~alpham8/application/
http://localhost/~alpham8/application/index/someaction/
http://localhost/~alpham8/application/web/img/someimage.png
```

But it does not work for:

```
http://localhost/~alpham8/application/somecontroller/someaction/
```

The none-working URL´s returns me an 404 error.

Please help me.

Comment: One thing that last RewriteRule is not needed and appears to be a dupe.

Comment: the last rule is for everything else, which does not match to the conditions above. So this is really needed here, isn´t it?

Comment: Then what is the purpose of the rule above it? The last rule is going to get any file or folder, even real ones. So it wil try to rewrite your CSS, JS and other files too. Is that what you really want?

Comment: no, every picture, css, js, etc. is located under web folder, which is excluded from the rewrite.

Comment: no one got an answer? Come on, I know about the apache experts here...